# Sort JFace Treeviewer multiple column

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'd like the user to be able to sort the `TreeViewer` anytime he wants to just by clicking the column header. However I don't know the proper way to do it.

I discovered that we can use `ViewerComparator` to sort different elements. However, I don't know how to set a listener to be able to ascending or descending sort properly.

Is there a way to have an ARROW automaticly with JFace Library to let the user choose descending or ascending in the column sort ?

Regards,
Waldo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really automatic.

You need to call `TreeColumn.addSelectionListener` to add a selection listener to deal with the clicks on the tree column headers.

You will then need to get the `Tree` from the `TreeViewer` with

```
Tree tree = viewer.getTree();
```

and then call

```
tree.setSortColumn(treeColumn);
```

to set the indicated main sort column and

```
tree.setSortDirection(SWT.UP) // or SWT.DOWN
```

to set the indicated sort direction.

Call

```
viewer.refresh();
```

to make the viewer redo the sorting.

You will need to track the column(s) to sort on in your comparator.

Comment: Oh thank you. I kinda did it just I didn't use setSortColumn and setSortDirection and directly, it's working but it should better do do it your way.