# Sort rows in JFace Treeviewer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, treeview, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'd like to sort the rows of my `TreeViewer` alphabetically, because every time I start the simulation, the rows of the tree are ordered randomly.

I found some methods to sort only by column with `setSortColumn(TreeColumn column)`. Is there an easy way to sort the tree by rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `setComparator` method of the viewer to provide a class based on `ViewerComparator` to sort the entries in your view.

If you just want to sort by the values of the labels returned by your label provider you can just use the base `ViewComparator` class:

```
viewer.setComparator(new ViewerComparator());
```

If your want your sorting to be more complex use a class extending `ViewerComparator` and override the `sort` method (perhaps also `category`).

Comment: This didn't work for me. My ```TreeViewer``` has 3 columns, with the left column being an expandable tree. I get the sort column and direction indication on column index 1 and 2 (sorting column 0 makes no sense, so I made clicking that header clear the sort). However, I see no sort action being performed whatsoever in terms of ordering the data in the UI. Why would this be if I just want to sort by the label provider? I have implemented the sorting as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766923/sort-jface-treeviewer-multiple-column

Comment: @majixin If you want to sort on columns you must use a Comparator that looks at the sort column settings and direction and does the appropriate sort. Just using ViewComparator does not do that. For any more details ask a new question with an [mre]

Comment: I have placed my particular use-case on a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322319/jface-treeviewer-sorting-updated